# .NET framework: new features

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-4.0

A few weeks ago I changed the target .NET framework for my application to the 4th version. Recently my Resharper told me that my variable "MetaDescription" hides property `string System.Web.UI.Page.MetaDescription`

After small investigation the piece of code that worked earlier:

```
    HtmlMeta MetaDescription = new HtmlMeta();
    MetaDescription.Attributes.Add("name", "description");
    MetaDescription.Attributes.Add("content", ((IFriendlySEO)Page).DescriptionString);
    Header.Controls.Add(MetaDescription);
```

was replaced with much more readable:

```
    MetaDescription = ((IFriendlySEO)Page).DescriptionString;
```

(same for MetaKeywords).

Question: is there any useful source that can give a list of such new features?

Question 2: is there any book (I mean printed version) of such items (I've seen "Essential C# 4.0", but it is for .NET newcomers only. Is there anything that could be fruitful for those who want to became a Guru?)

Thanks.

Comment: Did you look for "what's new" in MSDN? Maybe at the [.NET Framework Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/default.aspx), which has the [What's New in the .NET Framework 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868.aspx) link right on it?

Comment: John, thank you. That will be at least a good start!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think MSDN's [What's New in ASP.NET 4 and Visual Web Developer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s57a598e.aspx) page may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Good, similar for John's suggestion... But probably you also aware about any books about?